# converting date into char in AS400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I am trying to convert the current date - 2 months into format yyyymmdd and subtract 1900000 from it.

Oracle was easy for me

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'YYYYMMDD') - 19000000 FROM DUAL
```

Can some one suggest me the same for **AS400** .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick:

```
select char(((year(d)-1900) * 100 + month(d)) * 100 + day(d))    
from (select (curdate() - 2 months) as d from sysibm/sysdummy1) s
```

or if you prefer to do the same without nested select:

```
select char(((year(curdate() - 2 months) - 1900) * 100 
        + month(curdate() - 2 months)) * 100 
        + day(curdate() - 2 months))   
from sysibm/sysdummy1
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Simplest might be:

```
SELECT DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURDATE() - 2 MONTHS,ISO),'-',''))-19000000 FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1
```

Some thought might dig out something better. but it won't get a lot simpler no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
      DEC(SUBSTR(CHAR(DATE(NOW()) - 2 MONTHS), ISO), 1, 4)||
      SUBSTR(CHAR(DATE(NOW()) - 2 MONTHS), ISO), 6, 2)||
      SUBSTR(CHAR(DATE(NOW()) - 2 MONTHS), ISO), 9, 2), 8, 0) - 19000000
    FROM DUAL

Answer (score 0):

This is a litte late answer, but should do the trick :)

```
select char((year(curdate() - 2 months) * 100          
    + month(curdate() - 2 months)) * 100           
    + day(curdate() - 2 months))                   
from sysibm/sysdummy1
```

This is almost the same as karol.mlot's answer, however, you will be getting the right format since you asked for YYYYMMDD

Answer (score -1):

```
EVAL numericField = %dec(%date(alphaDate:*MDY/):*MDY)
```

The parm following the char field must be the format of the char field (I used *MDY with "/"for an example).

The parm at the end of the expression must be the format of the numeric field. 
So this example converts 11/22/2008 to 11222008.

If you want 2008-11-22 converted to 20081122 make both parms *ISO.

Comment: thanks but you please give me in the format of something like oracle which is select DEC(DATE((CURRENT_DATE -2 MONTHS),ISO) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 . I am to convert till yyyy-mm-dd but after that iam not able to . can you please guide. Thanks for your time and help